# Redraw table if search bar is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Based on [this discussion](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4222/server-side-ajax-search-wait-till-finish-entering/p1), added code below into my JS code to enable filtration to be triggered by pressing the enter key instead of keyup or delay.

```
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSetFilteringPressEnter = function (oSettings) {
    var _that = this;

    this.each(function (i) {
        $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
        var $this = this;
        var anControl = $('input', _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f);
        anControl.unbind('keyup').bind('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
                _that.fnFilter(anControl.val());
            }
        });
        return this;
    });
    return this;
}

/* Example call */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dataTable').dataTable().fnSetFilteringPressEnter();
} );
```

Now what I want to do is, when user removes keyword from search bar, I want to redraw table. Currently it doesn't redraw without pressing enter button. How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its safe to do on the keyup event of keyboard, unlike only triggering on the `enter` key press.

```
anControl.off('keyup').on('keypress', function (e) {
        $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
        _that.fnFilter(anControl.val());
});
```

Also, note I have used `on()` and `off()` for delegation instead of `bind` and `unbind` which are deprecated as of jQuery 1.7

Or, you can create a completely different handler for the specific case, where all the keywords are deleted on the text box.

```
    anControl.off('keyup').on('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
            _that.fnFilter(anControl.val());
        }
        if(anControl.val().length == 0) {
               //redraw table
        }

    });
```

Comment: The problem is, plug-in itself works by this behavior. My table gets all contents from PHP backend and this behavior of Datatables nearly DDos'es my webserver. That's why I'm using Enter button

Comment: Getting this error message `acControl is not defined` @ line `if(acControl.text().length == 0) {`

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu, that was a typo, use `anControl`

Comment: Also, not `anControl.text()` but `anControl.val()` :)  
Second problem is, now it works with Enter press. By default script sends request every time when you press key. Can we somehow wait for user to complete input and post request instead of one-by-one letter sending?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu, Of course it is what `keypress` does? You might want to use `blur` event, which triggers when the user moves away from the input box.

Answer (score 0):

mayb you can achieve what you need by using the `.blur` event of the jquery. when ever the textbox looses focus then.. simple set the filter to a empty string like this.

```
this.each(function (i) {
        $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
        var $this = this;
        var anControl = $('input', _that.fnSettings().aanFeatures.f);
        anControl.unbind('keyup').bind('keypress', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $.fn.dataTableExt.iApiIndex = i;
                _that.fnFilter(anControl.val());
            }
        });
        anControl.blur(function(){
            _that.fnFilter('');
        });
        return this;
    });
    return this;
```

Comment: But it also, looses focus when you change tab on Firefox for example.How to fix this problem? Second, now it works with Enter press. By default script sends request every time when you press key. Can we somehow `wait` for user to complete input and post request instead of one-by-one letter sending?